# DevExpress Skins not working

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

Does anyone what can cause the devExpress skin option for their controls to not work?

If I change the skinName of a control to `Office 2010 Black` for example, it doesn't do anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to register the skins. Normally, you apply a Application wide skin at application start-up.

See this article at [DevExpress online Documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3096).

Here's what I normally do:

`DevExpress.UserSkins.BonusSkins.Register();`
`DevExpress.UserSkins.OfficeSkins.Register();`

You'll need to add the references ot the DevExpress's Skin DLLs. And after that you can just use the skin you want:

`defaultLookAndFeel1.LookAndFeel.SetSkinStyle("Office 2010 Silver");`

Where `defaultLookAndFeel1` is a control dragged from the toolbox onto a WinForm. Dragging it to a base form is recommended. Then inherit remaining forms from the base form and all the application will give consistent Look & Feel.

**Update:**
Latest DevExpress has changed namespace for custom skins. The last two lines might be important for you.

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

DevExpress.UserSkins.BonusSkins.Register();
DevExpress.Skins.SkinManager.EnableFormSkins();
DevExpress.Skins.SkinManager.EnableMdiFormSkins();
```

Comment: Actually I didn't have to do any of this. All I was missing was the "useDefaultLookAndFeel". You have to turn it off for your custom skin to work.

To skin all the controls in a form, just make your form inherit from XtraForm and set the LookAndFeel there. Make sure all the controls in the form are set to use the default look.

Comment: However, you answer has helped me realize that the problem was that the main form was reading from the defaultLookAndFeel1 (even it if wasen't specified by me). So I will mark it as answer.

Comment: Just to add to this, some of the skins look best when the Glass interface is turned off for your form. (Win7 only), so I'd recommend setting the XtraForm AllowFormGlass to false.

Comment: I cannot find the property you mention. How do you get to it?

Comment: The AllowGlass property is now gone, last I checked.